# Please help identify this plant - we are worried!

Tags: identification

We recently moved into a new house, and noticed that this plant has grown up quite quickly.

Please could you help us identify what this is as we are quite worried it is something serious such as Japanese Knotweed or similar!

Any ideas what it is, or how we should deal with it to keep it under control, or how to best remove it? As you can tell, we are novice gardeners so any advice much appreciated!

For info we live in Winchester, UK.

Thank you so much for helping in advance...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it popping up all over the place or in just a single spot?

Comment: Just in one spot

Comment: Could be H. arborescens as suggested, but even if it doesn't turn out to be a Hydrangea variety, its most definitely NOT Japanese knotweed...

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a rather nice Hydrangea arborescens or similar species/hybrid. If so, you'll know it when it blooms. I'm fairly certain that it's Not Knotweed (stems seem to look very wrong for knotweed).

Comment: That is great thanks very much Jurp!